# How make salutation to multiple recipients `Dear Sussane, David & Joshua`? (and other queries)

Tags: grammar

For an exam answer, I was required to write a letter to invite my friends to my city. I have some specific queries about it, but I've put the whole thing for some context. The problem phrases are in bold.

> **Dear Sussane, David & Joshua**
>
> I am excited to receive **you all** on Sunday next week at Hyderabad Airport Central.
>     Therefore, there isn't any need to worry about logistics from airport to my home.
>
> Let me share the vacation plan that you would think of spending here. This city
>       has an history of Nizam Royal Family, whose heritage is **left behind** 400 years 
>      ago. Some of the obvious destinations that has to be visited are **Charminar, Golconda
>      Fort, Falaknuma Palace & Ramoji Film City.**
>
> Hyderabad hosts a **Zoological** park. Therefore, You could think of coming with 
>     children for this trip. Children can have some learning experience at Salarjung museum. >   For a comfortable trip this would not consume more than 4 days.
>      **Therefore, Please plan accordingly and make me informed before starting from 
>      there.**
>
> Yours lovely,
>
> Rebecca

My question:

1) Can i address the recipients with multiple names, when i write a letter? by saying `Dear A, B & C`

2) Could i use a better phrase than saying **left behind**?

3) Can the heritage destinations be mentioned with Initial Capitalise letter? for example: `Charminar` `Zoological`

4)  Can i better the wind-up statement at the end of the letter? Looks like I did not phrase it concisely `before starting from there`.

Comment: It is possible that you will need to split this question into multiple queries, but this seems a better fir in ELL

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can definitely address more than one person in the salutation. I would personally write out "and" and not use an ampersand.

(2) ...whose lineage dates back 400 years.

(3) If zoological park is part of the name, it's capitalized: The Miami Metro Zoo.

(4) I don't understand what you mean by "before starting from there."

Comment: I wonder if "before starting from there" is: _Please let me know your desires **before you leave**._ (In other words, before the trio begins their journey to visit).

Comment: Good point. I think you may be right.

Comment: @J.R.  'desires' look a bit awkward, may be i did not listen this word much in meetings for past 10 years

Comment: @CocoPop yes you are right, before my friends start from their place. BTW am always confused in usage of their and there.

Comment: @J.R. is right. The host is talking about when her guests start to fly to India. May be to know the schedule of flight and pick them up.

Comment: @J.R. Is this better? `Please let me know your thoughts before you leave`

Comment: @overexchange - _Please let me know your thoughts before you leave_ would be an excellent way to write it. Sounds very natural and understandable to me.

Comment: @J.R. when do we use word `desires`?

Comment: _desires_ might not have been such a good choice. Upon rereading my initial suggestion, it sounds a bit stilted. The word _desire_ is roughly synonymous with _want_. When giving someone a few options, you could say, "Please let me know what you want to do" (or, "Please let me know what you'd like to do").